# add unallocated partition to root partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I am a Debian 10 user, and I would like to expand the size of my root partition.

I have a lot of unallocated space, that I took from the sda3 partition, but I don't know how to add it to my sda6 partition (the root one).  How can I do that ?

[image]

If it is not possible to move the unallocated space, what alternative do I have to use conveniently this space, instead of filling the root partition ?

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to move partitions (even on running system), it can be tricky and I'd recommend not to - just create new partition(s) there instead and mount as /home, /var - or any other mount point where you want to keep your data.

If you'll move parts of the existing / to a new location, use something like `sudo rsync -aXS /home/ /mnt/new_home/` or tar to preserve permissions and extended attributes (if any)

Comment: So you are saying that I can mount my /dev/sda3 in /home, and it will store my data on it? Will it unmount when I turn my computer off ?

Comment: Yes, you can mount any partition into any location (assuming that filesystems are supported). If you want to make it persistent, you'll have to modify `/etc/fstab`.
Check [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) for additional information.